# How can I know whether the image generated using PHP is requested from my website or some other website?

Tags: php

How can I know when an image (generated with PHP) is called from my website or from another one?

I have tried with

`if(eregi("mydomain.com", $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME])`

but seem return always true even if

```
<img src='..linktofilephptogeneratetheimage..'   >
```

is located on anther server

Thanks

Comment: Simple note: Since PHP.net recommands to go to PHP5.3 eregi is gonna be depricated soon.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the page that refers to the image. Then match this path against the domain you're expecting the image to be accessed from (your own site).

If it's acceptable, then serve the image; if not, then echo a dummy image or something else.

*Note*: This variable can be manually edited by some web clients, but if you're simply trying to avoid people using your site to serve images on other pages, it should be reliable enough.

Comment: i've tied it just now but seem still dosen't work with
 if(!eregi("mydomain.com", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) die('error');

Comment: @oscurodrago: Use [strpos](http://php.net/strpos). ereg is deprecated (its replacement is [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)).

Comment: May I ask why you are using a depreciated PHP function? If you're simply trying to see if that domain name is in the referrer string, just use if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"mydomain.com")>-1) or if(preg_match("mydomain\.com",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])!=0).

Comment: ok i've used strpos and now it's work also i gereralized it with
if( ! strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) )